# Problem running Age of Empires III on VirtualBox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, age-of-empires-iii

I have a Ubuntu host and running Windows 7 as guest using VirtualBox.

I installed succesfully Age of Empires III, but whenever I try to run the game, got this error:

```
Initialization Failed Direct3D initialization failed.
```

In the log appears this line:

```
PreGame  6713:  nvCPL is unavailable.
```

I have tried all the solutions around the web to no avail.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: I think that a question like "How can I get Direct3D to run under VirtualBox" in superuser or askubuntu would be better. You should check out their rules first though.

Comment: You gave me the clue a was looking for. I had Direct3D disabled on my VM. The question you posted was the right one. Thank you.

Comment: I'll be posting it as answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says...

> Initialization Failed Direct3D initialization failed.

You should enable Direct3D in VirtualBox settings, if that doesn't work, you should try updating your drivers in both VM and host PC.